# jquery datepicker angularjs dateformat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am using a jqdatepicker in an html page using AngularJS directive. I am saving the date from jqdatepicker in to the database in format : 2016-08-30.
Here is the angular directive:

```
validationApp.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the html code:

```
<input type="text" ng-class="highlightDateColor($index)" ng-disabled="enableDisableDateAndStatus($index)" input-arrow select-me value="6858"
ng-init="date['field_'+$index]=row['FOLLOWUP_RMDR_DT']" value="{{row['FOLLOWUP_RMDR_DT']}}" name="date['field_'+$index]" 
 ng-model="date['field_'+$index]" jqdatepicker ng-change="reminderDateBlur(row,$index)" />
```

While setting the date, the jqdatepicker sets correct value in the database, but while retrieving it from database in the front end it shows:
2016-08-30T00:00:00

I want the output as : 08/30/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this by using $filter in angular js. I have created one factory which is having formatdate function, we can use this function whenever we need to format the value.

```
app.factory('helper', function ($filter) {
    return {
        formatdate: function (dateParam) {
            var date= $filter('date')(dateParam,'MM/dd/yyyy');
            return date;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are retrieving the value why don't you try like this **{{dateValue|date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}** in html. This will format your date as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks. I have tried this but not working as expected.